# replace a dollar sign $ with carriage return in a text editor

Tags: sublime-text

I have a text with dollar signs I wish to find the $ signs and replace each one with  a carriage return. Please note I do NOT want to remove carriage returns.
I can do this with sublime text 3 but sublime text 4 can not

Comment: By *"carriage return"*, do you actually mean Windows style CRLF line terminators? ... Also please provide a sample few lines and show an example of the expected end result in relation to that sample.

Comment: You may want to consult the manual of your text editor or use one that has such functionality. In Gedit, the former default editor of the Gnome desktop, you would search for `\$` and replace with `\n`, option "Regular expression" checked.

Comment: SublimeText 4 can most certainly do this. You may need to *copy* a new line and then paste it into the replace field 